# Resolve named Dependencies with Dependency Resolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I've noticed that when I register my dependencies via named overrides Dependency Resolver struggles to resolve components properly. Seems like the first instance is provided. Everything is fine with ctor injection.

Example:

*Registration*

```
RegisterProvider<IAccountProvider, AccountProvider>();
RegisterProvider<IAccountProvider, CustomAccountProvider>("customAccountProvider");
```

*Resolution*

```
var instance = DependecyResolver.Current.GetService<IAccountProvider>();
```

Cannot retrieve **customAccountProvider** instance.
It always refers to the first registered component ignoring named constraints.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple implementations of the same component you have to name them or mark them with marking interface. Here is a code example with naming the instances :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace ResolvingNamedInctances
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

            container.Register(Component.For<ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>().ImplementedBy<AccountProviderTypeSelector>());
            container.Register(Component.For<IAccountProviderSelector>().AsFactory(typeof(AccountProviderTypeSelector)));


            container.Register(Component.For<IAccountProvider>().ImplementedBy<DefaultAccountProvider>().Named("default"));
            container.Register(Component.For<IAccountProvider>().ImplementedBy<CustomAccountProvider>().Named("custom"));

            // uncomment this line in MVC app and use DependencyResolver instead of container
            //DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WindsorDependencyResolver(container.Kernel));

            var accountProviderSelector = container.Resolve<IAccountProviderSelector>();

            var defaultAccountProvider = accountProviderSelector.GetAccountProvider(); // default
            defaultAccountProvider.Provide();


            var customAccountProvider = accountProviderSelector.GetAccountProvider("custom");
            customAccountProvider.Provide();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class AccountProviderTypeSelector : ITypedFactoryComponentSelector
    {
        public Func<IKernelInternal, IReleasePolicy, object> SelectComponent(MethodInfo method, Type type, object[] arguments)
        {

            string providerName = arguments.Length > 0 ? (string)arguments[0] : "default";
            return (k, r) => k.GetHandlers(typeof(IAccountProvider))
                .Where(
                    h =>
                    {

                        return h.ComponentModel.Name == providerName;
                    })
                .Select(h => (IAccountProvider)k.Resolve(
                    h.ComponentModel.Name,
                    typeof(IAccountProvider),
                    new Arguments { },
                    r))
            .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public interface IAccountProviderSelector
    {
        IAccountProvider GetAccountProvider();
        IAccountProvider GetAccountProvider(string nameIdentifier);
    }

    public interface IAccountProvider
    {
        void Provide();
    }

    public class DefaultAccountProvider : IAccountProvider
    {
        public void Provide()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working in default AccountProvider");
        }
    }

    public class CustomAccountProvider : IAccountProvider
    {
        public void Provide()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working in standart CustomAccountProvider");
        }
    }
}
```